# Unzipping Taking A Long Time (about 200-800kbs)

Tags: zip

On Windows 8. Unzipping is unbearably slow, as is downloading for that matter. Just unzipped a 700mb .zip file and it took about 19 minutes at anywhere between 200-800kbs. This keeps happening.

I have one of the best SSDs: Samsung EVO 840 1TB

Computer is i7 3.2

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: the question can be helped by indicating what is being unzipped. if it is 20,000 files or 1 it would make a world of difference in how it unzipped, even for a SSD. If downloading speed is a problem, it would be important to tell how your connected, what speeds you get on speed tests.  I would suspect that anything as slow as what your indicating, you need to do a LOT more checking of your system, task manager, and resource monitor at the least.

Comment: Memory?  Anti-virus?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to let you down but the 840 EVO is not one of the best SSDs. I know I have 8 of them:

http://www.computerworld.com/article/2836082/samsung-delivers-fix-for-ssd-slowdowns.html

> One of Samsung's most affordable consumer solid-state drives is experiencing read slowdowns with older data, a problem the company has now addressed with a firmware upgrade and installation guide.

You probably need to run optimisation on them - I take it is running the latest firmware.  Installing Samsung Magician will give you all you need.